# Why are operations between different enum types allowed in another enum declaration but not elsewhere?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

The C# compiler allows operations between different enum types in another enum type declaration, like this:

```
public enum VerticalAnchors
{
    Top=1,
    Mid=2,
    Bot=4
}

public enum HorizontalAnchors
{
    Lef=8,
    Mid=16,
    Rig=32
}

public enum VisualAnchors
{
    TopLef = VerticalAnchors.Top | HorizontalAnchors.Lef,
    TopMid = VerticalAnchors.Top | HorizontalAnchors.Mid,
    TopRig = VerticalAnchors.Top | HorizontalAnchors.Rig,
    MidLef = VerticalAnchors.Mid | HorizontalAnchors.Lef,
    MidMid = VerticalAnchors.Mid | HorizontalAnchors.Mid,
    MidRig = VerticalAnchors.Mid | HorizontalAnchors.Rig,
    BotLef = VerticalAnchors.Bot | HorizontalAnchors.Lef,
    BotMid = VerticalAnchors.Bot | HorizontalAnchors.Mid,
    BotRig = VerticalAnchors.Bot | HorizontalAnchors.Rig
}
```

but forbids them inside method code, i.e. the operation:

```
VerticalAnchors.Top | HorizontalAnchors.Lef;
```

Is flagged with this error:

> Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'VerticalAnchors' and 'HorizontalAnchors'.

There's a workaround, of course:

```
(int)VerticalAnchors.Top | (int)HorizontalAnchors.Lef
```

I am curious about this compiler behaviour.  Why are operations between different enum types allowed in another enum declaration but not elsewhere?

Comment: I think you want to `|` instead of `&`.

Comment: The more obvious example of how the initializer expression is implicitly converted is `Top=1`.  You cannot write that either in a statement without using a cast.

Comment: Surprising. They could change their error message to _Operator '&' can be applied to operands of type 'VerticalAnchors' and 'HorizontalAnchors' only in the declaration of an enumeration constant._

Comment: @EricLippert Can you please quote from the spec where it says that enum logical operators **can** combine different enum types when we're inside the declaration of a (possibly unrelated) enum?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: "... the value of that constant expression implicitly converted to the underlying type of the enum is the associated value..." is the closes we get. See my answer for details.

Comment: @EricLippert this explains the final cast but it does not explain implicit conversions deeper down the tree of the constant expression (the binary and operator applied to different types). I'd be very interested to hear your expert judgement on my answer.

Comment: @EricLippert "the value of that constant expression" is, in any other place, an exception. it does not do `(int)(VerticalAnchors.Top & HorizontalAnchors.Lef);` it does `(int)(VerticalAnchors.Top) & (int)(HorizontalAnchors.Lef);`

Comment: @SWeko: You make a good point. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry for not have been more explicit. The question is: ¿Why the compiler allows operations between diffrent enums in another enum declaration and forbids them elsewhere? Is very dificult for me to write in english, and I forget question marks, etcétera, sorry again.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: yes, it must be | instead of & for the example to work as expected. But the example is only to illustrate the compiler behaviour question. Anyway, I edited the question to show | instead of &. Thanks.

Comment: Referenced in this ... [comment thread](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/#comment-9725).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is actually not in the [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664599%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as far as I can tell. There is something related:

> If the declaration of the enum member has a constant-expression
>   initializer, the value of that constant expression, **implicitly**
>   converted to the underlying type of the enum, is the associated value
>   of the enum member.

Although `VerticalAnchors.Top & HorizontalAnchors.Lef` has type `VerticalAnchors` it can be implicitly converted to `VisualAnchors`. But this does not explain why the constant expression itself supports implicit conversions everywhere.

Actually, it appears explicitly to be **against** the spec:

> The compile-time evaluation of constant expressions **uses the same
>   rules as run-time evaluation** of non-constant expressions, except that
>   where run-time evaluation would have thrown an exception, compile-time
>   evaluation causes a compile-time error to occur.

If I didn't miss something, the spec not only does not allows this explicitly, it disallows it. Under that assumption it would be a compiler bug.

Comment: "Within an enum member initializer, values of other enum members are always treated as having the type of their underlying type, so that casts are not necessary when referring to other enum members."

Comment: @hvd that is actually an interesting quote. But does this not refer to enum members *of the enum type under consideration*?

Comment: I must admit that would have been my first interpretation as well, but I think the compiler is right, that's not what it says.

Comment: @usr: @ Eric Lippert says that it is a known compiler flow, and you directly say that it is a compiler bug.

After reading both responses, and although I may be wrong because my English is not good, I think that in this case "bug" is more approximate than "flaw". So, I frame your response as the answer. I believe it is a compiler bug.

Anyway, as Eric says, it is a very handy bug for me ¿Can we say it is a ver handy compiler bug? I hope that they never fix it :)

Answer (score 11):

Since you did not ask a question in your question, I'll pretend that you asked some interesting questions and answer them:

> Is it true that inside an enum declaration, you can use values of other enums in the initializers?

Yes. You can say

```
enum Fruit { Apple }
enum Animal { Giraffe = Fruit.Apple }
```

Even though it would not be legal to assign `Fruit.Apple` to a variable of type `Animal` without a cast.

This fact is occasionally surprising. In fact, I myself was surprised. When I first tried doing that, to test part of the compiler, I thought it was a possible bug.

> Where in the spec does it say that is legal?

Section 14.3 says that the initializer must be a constant, and that the constant will be converted to the underlying type of the enum. Enum members are constants.

> Ah, but what about this case?

```
enum Fruit { Apple = 1 }
enum Shape { Square = 2 }
enum Animal { Giraffe = Fruit.Apple | Shape.Square }
```

> That expression isn't a legal constant expression in the first place, so what's up?

OK, you got me there. Section 14.3 does also say that enum members used in initializers do not need to be cast, but it is unclear as to whether it means members of *the enum being initialized* or members of *any enum*. Either is a reasonable interpretation, but without specific language, it is easy to think that the former meaning is the intended one.

This is thus a known flaw; I pointed it out to Mads a few years ago and it has never been resolved. On the one hand, the spec does not clearly allow it. On the other hand, the behaviour is both useful and in the spirit, if not entirely in the letter, of the specification.

Basically, what the implementation does is when it is processing an enum initializer, it treats all enum members as being constant expressions of their underlying type. (Of course, it does need to ensure that enum definitions are acyclic, but that is perhaps better left for another question.) It therefore does not "see" that `Fruit` and `Shape` do not have an "or" operator defined.

Though the spec wording is unfortunately not clear, this is a desirable feature. In fact, I used it frequently on the Roslyn team:

```
[Flags] enum UnaryOperatorKind { 
  Integer = 0x0001, 
  ... 
  UnaryMinus = 0x0100,
  ... 
  IntegerMinus = Integer | UnaryMinus
  ... }

[Flags] enum BinaryOperatorKind { 
  ...
  IntegerAddition = UnaryOperatorKind.Integer | Addition
  ... }
```

It is very handy to be able to mix-n-match flags taken from various enums.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Indeed, one of the hard parts about not knowing an answer is not knowing what question will elicit it. :-)

Comment: @usr: A while back someone set up a Twitter feed to do just that; a robot crawled my various postings and tweeted each one. The Twitter account was "ericlippert" and had my photo attached to it, so it was reasonable for people to believe it was me doing that. The guy did not think to, you know, *ask me first if that was OK*, which it most certainly was not. Since that violated Twitter's terms of service, I now own that feed. :-)  Perhaps someone else has built such a robot; I don't know. I am flattered by the attention; I'm surprised anyone else is interested in this stuff.

Comment: @usr You can do that for any SO user. The one you're looking for is http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/88656, though it lists comments too.

Comment: You can even do crazy stuff like `enum Animal { Giraffe = Fruit.Apple * Shape.Square << DayOfWeek.Thursday, }`. Normally you could never multiply or bit shift with operands of enum types, but here you can!

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you for your wonderful answers to my non-existent questions (sorry again). But the behavior seemed so strange to me, that most I felt curious to know how it is posible. Your answer has been the guide to know what really is happening. But I think that it is more accurate to say that it is a "bug". However, I hope it will be never fixed, because I agree with you that it is very handy.

Comment: FYI, commented on [here](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/#comment-9725)... By the very same 'user1816693'...

Comment: @PeterMortensen: The guy seems pretty vexed by what I intended to be just poking a little fun at a "question" that just made a bunch of statements, while making a good faith attempt to satisfy their curiosity. It's hard to convey that sort of intent I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

C# allows definition of enum values to contain constant value expression, so that an enum value can be a combination of enumerations, e.g. `[Flags]`.  The compiler evaulates each enum value in the expression as `int` (usually), thus you can do bitwise and arithmetic operations on the enum value.

Outside of an enum definition, you must cast the enum to a primitive type before performing an operation on it.

Comment: Listen: I cannot say `var local = DayOfWeek.Thursday | StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;` inside a method. But I can say `enum MyType { Member = DayOfWeek.Thursday | StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, }` inside a namespace (or nested in a class/struct). Why?

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is, why can you use **mixed** enum types.

Comment: As I said `evaluates ... to int (usually)`.  This is so for all enum type values in an definition expression.  I think it defaults to the underlaying type of the enum, which is by default an int.

Comment: _you must cast the enum to a primitive type before performing an operation_ More precisely: Outside of an enum, you can apply the operators `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `|`, `&`, and `^` to two enum values provided that (and only if) their types are the same. The result has the same type. (You can also use the `~` operator on a single enum value.)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. You can also ask why this is allowed:

```
enum MyType
{
  Member = DayOfWeek.Thursday | StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase,
}
```

when this is *not* allowed:

```
var local = DayOfWeek.Thursday | StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
```

The reason seems to be that inside the declaration of an enum, in the enum member initializers, any enum value, even a value of an unrelated enum, is considered to be cast to its underlying type. So the compiler sees the above example as:

```
enum MyType
{
  Member = (int)(DayOfWeek.Thursday) | (int)(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase),
}
```

I find this very strange. I knew that you could use values of the *same* enum directly (without stating the cast to the underlying type), as in the last line of:

```
enum SomeType
{
  Read = 1,
  Write = 2,
  ReadWrite = Read | Write,
}
```

but I find it very surprising that *other* enums' members are also cast to their underlying integer types.

Comment: It's also reasonable that you can provide any constant integral expression for an enum initializer (including other enums).  Being able to mix-and-match is however VERY weird.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Now we know that all enum types are ever converted to their underlying types in declarations, the question can be extended to any use of an enum type in enum declarations. Thanks.