# Overload resolution when applying operator | to enums of distinct types

Tags: c#, enums, overload-resolution

After reading the recent question [Operations between different enum types are allowed in another enum declaration but not elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541668/) I've come up with this example:

```
    enum Alpha : long
    {
        X,
    }

    enum Beta : ulong
    {
        X,
    }

    enum Gamma : long
    {
        X = Alpha.X | Beta.X,   // problem?
    }

    enum Delta : ulong
    {
        X = Alpha.X | Beta.X,   // no problem?
    }
```

Result of compiling: `Gamma` will not compile (*CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ulong' to 'long'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*). `Delta` compiles happily.

Is *this* not something not to be expected from the C# Language Specification?

(Note: If I change the member of `Alpha` to be initialized to a negative constant, like `-1L`, then neither `Gamma` nor `Delta` will compile.)

Comment: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/07/01/enums-are-evil/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's expected and it's not something enum-specific. You can simplify it to:

```
long a = 1L | 1UL; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'ulong' to 'long'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
ulong b = 1L | 1UL;
```

The following quotes from the C# Language Specification describes why it happens.

> **6.1.9 Implicit constant expression conversions**
>
> An implicit constant expression conversion permits the following conversions:
>
> ·         A constant-expression (§7.19) of type int can be converted
>   to type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value
>   of the constant-expression is within the range of the destination
>   type.
>
> ·         *A constant-expression of type long can be converted to type
>   ulong, provided the value of the constant-expression is not negative.*
>
> **6.1.2 Implicit numeric conversions**
>
> The implicit numeric conversions are:
>
> ·         From long to float, double, or decimal.
>
> ·         *From ulong to float, double, or decimal.*

In other words, `Alpha.X` (if the underlying value is positive) can be (an actually is!) implicitly converted to `ulong`. But the result of `Alpha.X | Beta.X` is `ulong`, which, according to the specs, cannot be implicitly converted to the `long`.

But once you change the `Alpha.X` to be initialized to a negative constant, like `-1L`, then, according to the quote above, it can no longer be implicitly converted to `ulong` and compilation will fail with a different error: `Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'ulong'`

Comment: Ah, now I see it. So for **constant** expressions there exist more implicit conversions than there does for non-constant expressions. In particular there's an implicit conversion from `long` to `ulong` (for constant expressions) but not the other way. Explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's expected, there's no implicit conversion from ulong to any integral type.

As soon as you tell the compiler that you long is -ve, you give it enough information to say, you don't want to do that.

Personally I'd have been happy for it to get upset with long | ulong, but no doubt some C programmers influenced that decision. :(

Comment: There's also "no implicit conversion from **`long`** to any integral type", so one would think it were symmetrical. Yet it works for `Delta`, but not for `Gamma`. The value zero is in range for both `long` and `ulong` (symmetrical again), so where does the asymmetry come from?

Comment: I think they got this one wrong as well, but not because of symmetry. They've treated it like byte to word and word to byte. +ve long to ulong is safe, because you don't lose information.